# Is there any API or Third Party API in / for Android SDK to use to fascilitate image editing in android application?

Tags: android, image

I am trying to build an image editing application for android. As there are lots of other such application but I want to develop my own. So if anyone knows something about the Image editing implementation in android application development, please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally after googling over some times I found [OpenCV](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/) as a Image Processing and More functional API, and its cross platform.

Comment: I have the same requiremnet . Can you please share how you did it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[Aviary by adobe](https://developers.aviary.com/) and [Fotor](http://developers.fotor.com/) are very powerful and rich image editing sdk for Android,IOS and web